# Cannot convert a date of MMM, dd yyyy to a dd/MM/yyyy in Android

Tags: android, date, datetime, android-datepicker

I am trying to convert a date of MMM, dd yyyy to a format of dd/mm/yyyy in order to update a date picker but I get an error in parse method on the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM, dd yyyy");
Date newDate = format.**parse**(strCurrentDate);

format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = format.format(newDate);
```

and

```
 String str[] = date.split("/");
 int myday = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
 int mymonth = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
 int myyear = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
 dp.updateDate(myday,mymonth,myyear);
```

What I am doing wrong here? Should I enclose it with try / catch?
thank you

Comment: Show us example date string

Comment: parse is not deprecated?

Comment: Then why I get java.text.ParseException? and How I can fix it?

Comment: show `strCurrentDate` content example. The error says that it is not in `MMM, dd yyyy` format

Comment: Sep, 1 2016 is an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will sure work.

```
 String inputPattern = "MMM, dd yyyy";
        String outputPattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern,Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date date = null;
        String str = null;

        try {
            String strCurrentDate = "Sep, 1 2016";
            date = inputFormat.parse(strCurrentDate);// it's format should be same as inputPattern
            str = outputFormat.format(date);
            Log.e("Log ","str "+str);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: We fixed the exception but Even if strCurrentDate has value of Sep, 1 2016  I get null as a result

Comment: Sorry,I have checked with "Sep, 1 2016" and it's working perfect.
Check my updated code snippet

Comment: A comma in wrong place did the mess I thought it was mmm, dd yyyy but it was mmm dd, yyyy thank you very much!!!for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse your string using a SimpleDateFormatter(SDF) like follows

```
String strDate = "MM, dd yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date dateStr = formatter.parse(strDate);
```

Use this to parse the string into a Date, and then your other SDF to turn that Date into the format you want.

Comment: READ THE QUESTION before you answer please! thank you

Comment: I did if you are not skilled enough to understand the answer i can't help it.

Comment: I all mean is that we say the same thing!! you answer with my question actually